# ELSE statement acting funny

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with a line of code. My teacher doesn't even see the problem and I've been fighting it for almost a week and a half.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
{
  if (count($_POST['CINS']) > 0)
  {
    echo "<h2>Your CINS picks are:</h2>\n";
    echo "<ul>\n"; 
    foreach ($_POST['CINS'] as $element)
    {
      echo "\t<li>$element</li>\n";
    } // end of FOREACH statement
    echo "</ul>\n";
  } // end of IF count CINS

  if (count($_POST['CINT']) > 0 ) 
  {
    echo "<h2>Your CINT picks are:</h2>\n";
    echo "<ul>\n"; 
    foreach ($_POST['CINT'] as $element2)
    {
      echo "\t<li>$element2</li>\n";
    } // End of FOREACH CINT
    echo "</ul>\n";
  } // End of IF for CINT
  else
  {
    echo "CINT = " . count($_POST['CINT']) . " CINS = " . count($_POST['CINS']) . "<br />\n";
    echo __LINE__;
    if ((count($_POST['CINT'] == 0)) and (count($_POST['CINS'] == 0)))  // This is where the problem lies. It's showing up the echo statements even when CINS has a count of 1. but if CINT has a count of 1, the echo statements do not show up. 
    {
      echo "<h2>No classes</h2>\n";
      echo "<p>You need to pick a class from BOTH CINT and CINS to be a well rounded student.</p>\n";
      echo "CINT = " . count($_POST['CINT']) . " CINS = " . count($_POST['CINS']) . "<br />\n";
    }
  } // END ELSE COUNT CINS
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean with funny?

Comment: you input a name and then select checkboxs from CINT and CINS classes and then display which CINS and / or CINT classes.  but if you select neither, then it displays the echo in the bottom else statement, but if you select one or the other, it should show no error.

Comment: Download a free IDE it'll save you from these types of errors. Netbeans has a light weight php version that does syntax highlighting, auto code completion and auto formatting (indenting).

Comment: Download Notepad++. It will also help with ***indentation***.

Comment: Week and a half? Really?

Comment: yeah. I'm a sucker for trying to get it on my own. and I have 4 other classes to deal with.    I have notepad ++, but it didn't see any issues... atleast that I saw.

Answer (score 3):

misplaced brackets

```
if ((count($_POST['CINT'] == 0)) and (count($_POST['CINS'] == 0))) -> wrong

if ((count($_POST['CINT']) == 0) and (count($_POST['CINS']) == 0))
```

Comment: Ay @Nick Thank you cibə girmir . Quş qoyda camaat əziyət çəkib.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those parentheses:

```
if(
    count($_POST['CINT']) == 0 AND
    count($_POST['CINS']) == 0
    )
```

Look how some indentation goes a long way:

```
{
    if (count($_POST['CINS']) > 0) {
        echo "<h2>Your CINS picks are:</h2>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n"; 
        foreach ($_POST['CINS'] as $element) {
            echo "\t<li>$element</li>\n";
        }

        echo "</ul>\n";
    }

    if (count($_POST['CINT']) > 0 ) {
        echo "<h2>Your CINT picks are:</h2>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n"; 
        foreach ($_POST['CINT'] as $element2) {
            echo "\t<li>$element2</li>\n";
        }

        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
else {
    echo "CINT = " . count($_POST['CINT']) . " CINS = " . count($_POST['CINS']) . "<br />\n";
    echo __LINE__;

    if(
        count($_POST['CINT']) == 0 AND
        count($_POST['CINS']) == 0
        ) {
        echo "<h2>No classes</h2>\n";
        echo "<p>You need to pick a class from BOTH CINT and CINS to be a well rounded student.</p>\n";
        echo "CINT = " . count($_POST['CINT']) . " CINS = " . count($_POST['CINS']) . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I do indent. I just do it later. otherwise to me it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want this:

```
if (count($_POST['CINS']) > 0)
{
    …
} // End of IF for CINS

if (count($_POST['CINT']) > 0 ) 
{
    …
} // End of IF for CINT

if (count($_POST['CINS']) == 0 || count($_POST['CINT']) == 0 ) 
{
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps parentheses need attention...

Your

```
if ((count($_POST['CINT'] == 0)) and (count($_POST['CINS'] == 0)))
```

might work better as

```
if ((count($_POST['CINT']) == 0) && (count($_POST['CINS']) == 0))
```

Give it shot - reply with outcome.

Comment: It fixed the problem. Thanks to all who helped.